# window.open("dle?dddjjkkk", "", "_blank"")

Tags: window.open

I need to open a new window with uri "dle?dddjjkkk".Everytime i tried ,http://localhost/sitename is appended with the url.Need help to open the new window with only the specified uri.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you use `window.open("dle?dddjjkkk", "", "_blank")` it will think it is a relative url, if you want it to go to that location you will need to put `http://`, or whatever the protocol is you want, in front of the url

Comment: i have used window.open("dle?dddjjkkk", "", "_blank") as u have suggested but its opening http://localhost/sitename/dle?dddjjkkk. I want only the dle?dddjjkkk in the address bar and not http://localhost/sitename part.

Comment: i said that it will think of it as a relative url, and that for getting the result you want, you would need to put `http://` in front of the url like this: `window.open("http://dle?dddjjkkk", "", "_blank")`

Comment: window.open("http://dle?dddjjkkk", "", "_blank") will not serve my purpose.I need only "dle?dddjjkkk" in the address bar without http:// .But my problem was solved and thank you for the effort.